# An error with coding in Django 1.9.2

Tags: python, django

I've created a model and two values in database. The first in Cyrillic and the second in Latin.

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Lecturer(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField('First name', max_length=200)
    mname = models.CharField('Middle name',max_length=200)
    lname = models.CharField('Last name', max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}" .format(self.fname, self.mname, self.lname)
```

[It seems work fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pzxe.png)

But when I try to click on link and edit the Cyrillic value I get an error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/lecturers/lecturer/2/change/
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/lecturers/lecturer/2/change/
Django Version: 1.9.2
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 80
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/vald/project',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Tue, 2 Feb 2016 20:30:07 +0200
```

Comment: Are you using Python3.x or 2.7? If 3.x then how do you run your dev server, python manage.py runserver?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Then replace __str__ to __unicode__, it should work,

Comment: Thanks, it works as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the `__str__` method over `__unicode__` in Python 2.7 use the provided [python_2_unicode_compatible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible) decorator:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Lecturer(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField('First name', max_length=200)
    mname = models.CharField('Middle name',max_length=200)
    lname = models.CharField('Last name', max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}" .format(self.fname, self.mname, self.lname)
```

Otherwise you'll have to use `__unicode__` over `__str__`.

Comment: No problem! @VladyslavKrylasov

Comment: nice slides about unicode in python: http://acdha.github.io/djangocon-internationalization-tutorial/handling-unicode.html